# One partial derivative equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: D \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function, where $D \subset \mathbb R^2$. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is identically zero in $D$. Does this mean that $f$ is independent of $y$ in this domain? For which domains $D$ is this true?

This is my attempt. For the first question, if we take $f(x, y) = xy$ and $D = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x = 0\}$. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x$  is identically zero in D, but $f$ is not independent of $y$.

As for the second question, I think that it would be enough that $D$ does not intersect any axes.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: $f$ is independent of $y$ in your example,  on $D$ it just the constant function $f(x,y)=0$

Comment: Does $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ even exist in your $D$?

Comment: @Alan: You're right. Would $f(x, y) = x + (y-1)^2$ with $D$ being the line $y = 1$ a more appropriate example?

Comment: @MichaelHartley: I think so. Why wouldn't it exist?

Comment: Domain is usually defined as an open connected set. Your set $D$ is not a domain.

Comment: @Rob32409 correct, my bad

Comment: For your second example, if D is the domain $y=1$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ doesn't make sense, since $y$ can't change.

Comment: My intuition says it should be correct, since if the partial in the y direction is 0 throughout the (open connected) domain,  the function is constant on vertical lines,  thus the value depends only on $x$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: In that case, the statement should be true always. That is, for every open connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$  $f$ is always independent of y, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @Rob32409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true for open connected sets in general.

Consider $D=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 1< |(x,y)|< 2,\text{ and } x>0\}$, the half annulus with inner radius 1, and outer radius 2. Let $u$ be defined as follows
$$
u(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(1-x)^2, &  0<x<1,\,\text{ and }  y<0,\\
0, & 1\leq x <2,\\
-(1-x)^2, & 0<x<1, \, \text{ and } y>0.
\end{cases}
$$
I leave it up to you to check that the partial derivative $\partial u/\partial y=0$ throughout $D$, but clearly $u$ depends on $y$ (since the values depend on whether $y>0$ or $y<0$).

The issue here is that you can hide regions of $D$ from each other; in particular your intuition is correct for sets $D$ for which you can't do this, i.e. for $D$ convex and open (though I will say that being convex is a sufficient condition, I have not thought if these are all).

Comment: Hello! I am wondering can you answer a few questions please since I am little confused. 1) what is the idea behind this example? 2) Why this function depends on $y$?