# When would a zero partial derivative guarantee that the function is independent of the variable?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

I have doubts on my solution of a problem in Zorich's book Mathematical Analysis (10.4.3.4). I will copy the problem here and then provide my solution.

**Problem**:

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ of a smooth function $f : D \to R$ defined in a domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of the xy-plane is identically zero. Is it true that $f$ is then independent of $y$ in this domain? For which domains $D$ is this true?

**my idea**:
Not true. Although the function itself doesn't include y anywhere, the value of y can still play a role through the intervals of the subfunctions of a piecewise function. And [the other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202784/one-partial-derivative-equal-to-zero) on the same question contains an example. My suggestion for the second part is then that the domain has to be convex. But I feel this could be too strong a condition.

If convexity is the answer, then I have the following statement to prove

> $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ , D is a convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, f is smooth, and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}p = 0 \;\forall p \in D \Longrightarrow \forall p,q \in D,p_x = q_x, f(p) = f(q)$)

Since the function is a real-value function, and the domain is convex, I can use the mean value theorem, which states that for any two points p and q that have the same x variable, there is a point $c \in \overline{pq}^{\circ} \subset D$ so that

> $f(q) - f(p) = f'(c)(q-p) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(c))(q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y)^T = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c)(q_x-p_x)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(c)(q_y-p_y)=0 $

This shows that f is independent of y.

I'm suspicious of my answer also because I haven't used the continuity of $Df$ in my proof.

Comments and suggestions are appreciated. ;)

Comment: Convexity is too strong. Any connected open set $D$ will do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you give a hint to how one should approach to prove this?

Comment: I think you need $\{y | (x,y) \in D \}$ to be connected, otherwise you could take a horseshoe shaped $D$ where $y$ crosses the two separate legs and $f$ has different (but locally constant) values on each leg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(t) = \begin{cases} e^{-1 \over t},& t>0 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, and define
$f(x,y) = ( \operatorname{sgn}x ) \phi(y)$ on $D = \{ (x,y) \mid y \ge |x| \}^c$.

Then $f$ is smooth on $D$ but for $y>0$ $f(x,y) = -f(-x,y) \neq 0$.

On the other hand, if $D$ is convex, then $D_y = \{ y \mid (x,y) \in D \}$ is connected (an interval, in fact) and $f$ is constant on $D_y$, hence independent of $y$

Comment: Your example cleared my confusion! Thank you. I wasn't able to come up with such an example to convince myself that connectedness isn't sufficient.  

just one small question, sgn(x) is not differentiable at 0, but this doesn't affect the smoothness of the function, because when x = 0, f is the zero function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @YanLin Yes. There are basically two cases to consider, $x=0$ and $x \neq 0$ and it is straightforward to check that $f$ is smooth on each.