# Partial derivative of rational function is identically zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, rational-functions

Let $f:D\to\mathbb R$ be the following rational function
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}{Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)},
$$
where here $P,Q$ are polynomials and
$$
D=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):Q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\neq0\}.
$$
**My question:** I want to prove that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=0$ for all $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in D$, then $f$ is independent of $x_1$.

**My attempt:** I saw in the posts [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202784/one-partial-derivative-equal-to-zero) and in [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202784/one-partial-derivative-equal-to-zero) that this is not true for $f$ in general, but if $D$ is convex, then it is true. Can I assume that $D$ is convex in the case of rational functions? If not, is there another way to prove that claim?

Comment: D is definitely not convex. If you put a line through any zero x of Q, there will be a lot of points on either side of x on the line.

But, you can cover D with open convex sets, which I think could lead to a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Cecilia. Do you mean *finite* cover? But still, I don't see how to prove that every such domain can be covered.